# GORM Instance Object Thread Safety

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Say I have the following domain classes. An `Employee` and a `Company` with a many to one relationship

```
class Employee {

    String id
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    Company company

    static mapping = {
        table name: "employee"
        id column: "employee_id", generator:"assigned"

        version false
    }
}

class Company {
    String id
    String name

    static hasMany = [employees:Employee]

    static mapping = {
        table name: "company"
        id column: "company_id", generator:"assigned"

        autoImport false
        version false
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is grab a `Company` object from the database, and then spawn off multiple threads to create `Employees` for the Company. However, I'm unsure if the `Company` object will be thread safe.

For instance:

```
public void createEmployees(companyId, employees){

    // Find the new created company - this is on the main thread
    Company company = Company.findById(companyId) // Is company thread safe?
    def lines = parseEmployees(employeeFile) // parses info about each employee that will later be used to create employee objects
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)

    List futures = new ArrayList()

    lines.each { line ->

        Future future = executor.submit(new Callable() {
            public def call() throws Exception {
                def employee = saveEmployee(line, company) // Is the company object thread safe here?
                return employee
            }
        });
        futures.add(future)
    }

    executor.shutdown()

    for(Future future : futures){
        def employee = future.get()
        println employee
    }
}

public Employee saveEmployee(line, company) {

    Employee employee = new Employee()

    employee.firstName = line.firstName
    employee.lastName = line.lastName
    employee.email = employee.email
    employee.id = line.id
    employee.company = company // thread safe?

    employee.save()
}
```

Again, I'm not sure if the Hibernate managed `Company` object passed to the `saveEmployee` method is thread safe or not. My understanding is that each `Thread` in the `Executor` will have its own Hibernate Session which is not thread safe. I thought I might need to call `merge` or `attach` on the `Company` object, but it appears that I don't. Everything seems to work fine, but it can be hard to tell when it comes to multi threading.

Answer (score 1):

In your provided example, the `Company` object passed is not modified, so it doesn't matter if it's thread-safe or not.  (It's not though; if you make changes to it in multiple threads you're going to get StaleObjectStateExceptions.)

Your `Company` `hasMany` employees, and in your current mapping the reference is actually stored in `Employee` (probably a company_id field).  Since you are not technically modifying the `Company` object when you are associating it with an employee, this will not cause problems.

There are a lot of ways to confirm this (since it is really hard to test all weird threading edge cases!) but in my opinion the easiest is probably by confirming that the `version` field on your `Company` object does not increase when you add new employees.  If that is not increasing, you can be confident that it is not being modified, and so threading does not come into play here.